# Are category isomorphisms also homomorphisms?

Tags: category-theory

[image]

In any set with structure, we define isomorphisms as being homomorphisms with the extra property of bijection. I'm reading a book about category theory and the definiton is only about bijection. There's no $F(f\circ g) = F(f)\circ F(g)$. Is this implicit and I can't see?

Comment: There isn't a class of "homomorphisms" in a category.

Comment: An arrow in a category is often called a morphism. So $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a morphism from $A$ to $B$. Suppose you work in the category of groups, then the objects of the category are groups and the arrows are the group homomorphisms. The notion of isomorphism as defined in your post then simply corresponds to a bijective group homomorphism.

Comment: one has to be a little bit careful! When $X$ and $Y$ are sets with some extra structure, the correct general notion of an isomorphism between them is _not_ a bijective homomorphism! Rather, one has to take a homomorphism $f\colon X\to Y$ which has an inverse $g\colon X\to Y$ _that is also a homomorphism_. Bijectivity implies that the inverse $g$ exists (as a map of sets), but $g$ might not necessarily be a homomorphism itself. The most common case is if $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, and homomorphism=continuous map. It is not true that the inverse of a continuous bijection is continuous.

Comment: In $F(f \circ g) = F(f) \circ F(g)$ what are $F$, $f$, and $g$? From the context, $f$ and $g$ are presumably arrows (aka morphisms) in a category. But then $F$ is something which **acts on those morphisms**. In other words, $F$ is something **outside of the category under discussion**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given definition is talking about *homomorphisms between two objects in a category*, and what it means for such a thing to be an isomorphism.

From your question, your trouble is that you have a different context in mind and so you misunderstand the definition — you are thinking about what a homomorphism *between two categories* would be. Such a thing is called a *functor*, and $F(g \circ f) = F(g) \circ F(f)$ is among the properties required for $F$ to be a functor.